# Unable to resolve HttpClient when using AddHttpClient in a .Net Generic Host that is not HTTP Server Implementation

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

I have built a command-line app using .net core 3.0 using the Generic Host Builder.  If I add a HttpClient to the services using AddHttpClient the the service requesting HttpClient fails to resolve with an error "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'"

If I register HttpClient myself then it resolves, so it appears that the AddHttpClient does not work unless it is a Http Server.

I find the whole AddHttpClient approach a bit more attractive as I can easily add policies etc.  In fact I am trying to create a reusable component that I can share between applications(web and non-web) which builds a consistent HttpClient.

Building Host

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHttpClient(); // This fails to resolve HttpClient
                //services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(provider => new HttpClient());    //This resolves okay
                services.AddSingleton<TestClass>();
            });
```

Classes requiring HttpClient which fail to resolve

```
    public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public TestClass(HttpClient client)
    {

    }
}

public interface ITestClass
{
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#typed-clients). `AddHttpClient` just adds the factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddHttpClient` just adds the factory

You are looking for a [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#typed-clients).

```
//...
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
    services.AddHttpClient<ITestClass, TestClass>();

})
//...
```

Comment: apologies, may of misunderstood your answer, if I add your line to my solution then  that works.